# Excel 2003 VBA Write to SQL Server 2000 ADO

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, runtime-error, adodb

We are working on changing an existing excel form to deliver a record to our SLQ server.

We have been scuccessful with code that scrubs captures and writes the data to the server using a DSN and ODBC.

`scn = dsn=ODBC123`

Our target users (of wich there are many) are using excel 2003 and an ODBC connection on each terminal is not practical.

This is my first venture into using ADODB.

I was tripping my badSQL message but do not get an error from the server, until I added the UID and Pass.

Now I am getting
  Run-time error '-2147467559(80004005)':
     Automation error 
     Unspecified Error

Would one of you fine ladies and/or gentlemen take a look and provide some guidence?

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ssql As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Const scn As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
    "Persist Security Info=False;" & _
    "Initial Catalog="DB on Server";" & _
    "Data Source="Server Name" & _ 
    "User ID=Form;Password=nope;"

ssql = "sql statment that writes a record to a table using info in the excel form," & _
" writen in vb that has worked through an odbc"

With cn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open scn
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    Set rst = .Execute(ssql)
End With
    On Error GoTo badsql:

rs.Open ssql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
On Error GoTo badsql:

rs.Close
cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing


MsgBox ("This record was updated in the database and documented for" & _
" processing. Please close this workbook.")


badsql:
    MsgBox ("This record was not processed please resubmit.")
    Exit Sub'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seem to have both `rst` and `rs` as `Recordset` objects. I don't see a declaration for `rst` in the supplied code.

In any case, the query string in `ssql` is run twice. Once when it gets executed and the results (if any) returned into `rst`. The other time when `rs` is opened.

You probably only want to run the query string once and, as it seems to be an `INSERT`-type query, you probably want to use `cn.Execute` rather than `rs.Open`

Comment: Thanks Barrowc I ended up changing the code quite a bit but the rst and rs was an issue.